# Naming Conventions with Class properties in Methods

Tags: c#

I currently have this source of code as an example:

```
class Person
{
    public Person create(string _name, int _uid)
    {
        return new Person()
        {
            name = _name,
            uid = _uid,
        };
    }

    public int uid;
    public string name;
}
```

I know it isn't the biggest of deals but I work on projects that have multiple developers meaning conventions are important.

On the official .NET naming conventions documentation, it states do-not use symbols however, this method is for the use of adding to a `List<Person> People = new List<Person>();` and is called like so:

```
People.Add(Person.create("Example", 1));
```

I have looked at sources like:

[C# Property Examples](http://www.dotnetperls.com/property)

Which they use a prefix `_` to declare its only temp to get or set a value which I then copied.

My question is, does this follow the .NET naming conventions or how can I keep it similar to the property names that currently exist?

Comment: The examples you've linked to use `_` in the name of the *field*, not the name of the *parameter*.

Comment: Exactly, which is why I am asking if copying that for a parameter follows the .NET conventions or whether it doesn't and if it doesn't, what can I use that stays similar to the property names.

Comment: Why do you need a `Create` method here?  Why don't you use a constructor instead?

Comment: I am changing that, its already been mentioned @DarrenYoung Thanks though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The convention is to use `camelCase` for parameter names, so they should be named `name` and `uid`. It doesn't matter whether they're temporary, or long-lived, whether you use them and discard them or store them in a field.

While on the subject of naming conventions, methods should be named using `PascalCase`, so I would rename `create` to `Create`.

Your public fields should actually be properties (see Jon Skeet's [Why Properties Matter](http://csharpindepth.com/articles/chapter8/propertiesmatter.aspx) for a complete explanation why), and should also be named using `PascalCase`.

```
public int Uid { get; private set; }
public string Name { get; private set; }
```

Finally, I'd question why the `Person` class has a non-static method to create an instance of `Person`. `joe.Create("mike", 123)` doesn't make much sense to me.

---

MSDN has a nice list of naming conventions [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229043(v=vs.110).aspx).

The only thing it's missing is using a leading underscore + snakeCase for *private* fields (e.g. `_myAge`). This is not endorsed by Microsoft, although it's a widely used convention. It's also encouraged by some refactoring tools such as ReSharper.

Comment: That hits the nail on the head, brilliant. You also opened a door to my infrastructure, I'll look into creating it static and correcting where stated. Thanks!

Comment: Regarding the method, I wanted to keep it object orientated so new comers can use easy methods to do things

Comment: @KyleE4K You're welcome :) I've added a link to Microsoft's naming conventions which might be of help. Regarding the create method, have you considered exposing a simple constructor instead? That's a good object-oriented approach.

Comment: That is true! I come from PHP and am new to C# so I want to get as used to conventions and approaches to infrastructural code as fluent as possible. This is really appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the *readonly* keyword

**IMHO** prefix "_" for any variables is **not** common for c#

code source https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/acdd6hb7.aspx

```
public class ReadOnlyTest
{
   class SampleClass
   {
      public int x;
      // Initialize a readonly field
      public readonly int y = 25;
      public readonly int z;

      public SampleClass()
      {
         // Initialize a readonly instance field
         z = 24;
      }

      public SampleClass(int p1, int p2, int p3)
      {
         x = p1;
         y = p2;
         z = p3;
      }
   }

   static void Main()
   {
      SampleClass p1 = new SampleClass(11, 21, 32);   // OK
      Console.WriteLine("p1: x={0}, y={1}, z={2}", p1.x, p1.y, p1.z);
      SampleClass p2 = new SampleClass();
      p2.x = 55;   // OK
      Console.WriteLine("p2: x={0}, y={1}, z={2}", p2.x, p2.y, p2.z);
   }
}
/*
 Output:
    p1: x=11, y=21, z=32
    p2: x=55, y=25, z=24
*/
```